# youtube-dl appears dead - what can I use to download videos?

Tags: youtube-dl, alternative

Judging by the huge number of [unresolved issues](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues) plus zero activity or communication from the project maintainers, the `youtube-dl` project appears to be dead and many of the project's contributors have moved on.

When I use the latest version `youtube-dl`, I only get a 75 KB/sec download rate, which can take many hours to download a video, and it doesn't support a site that I recently started using.

I'm not interested in hosting local `git` repositories, compiling code, modifying python files or commands.

What alternatives are there to `youtube-dl` that are relatively easy to install and are actively supported?

A recent [versionupdate](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/releases/tag/2021.12.17) to the project by the project's maintainer includes a [commit](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/commit/21b759057502c6e70d51011cfb3fb86d84055182) for the resignation of the maintainer which is further evidence that project is abandoned and therefore most likely dead.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132415/discussion-on-question-by-paul-youtube-dl-appears-dead-what-can-i-use-to-downl).

Answer (score 5):

The [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) project seems to be what many `youtube-dl` users and contributors have migrated to.

Since `yt-dlp` is ultimately a fork of `youtube-dl`, it is largely a drop-in replacement. For YouTube downloads, it will download at the same rates as `youtube-dl`, but it also includes many upgrades, including support for many new websites to download videos from.

The project supports using pip to install:

```
python3 -m pip install -U yt-dlp
```

This same command is also used when updating `yt-dlp`.

Basic options and command line usage for `yt-dlp` are nearly identical to `youtube-dl`, but more advanced options have changed so reading the project's main [GitHub page](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) is recommended.

Answer (score -1):

`youtube-dl` is back as the [official webpage](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme) claims.
I usually use `brew` to keep my sanity intact while switching back and forth between Mac and Linux. Just installed it on Ubuntu 20.04
`brew install youtube-dl`
It is working. Happy downloading. Cheers!!
[youtube-dl working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWEG6.png)

Comment: Take a look at the date on that update - it is June 5. Then, read and review the question and the links, because your answer does not provide a solution to the problem.

Comment: The first time I didn't notice your linked image includes the miserable download rate that I stated in the question.